What claims about the real numbers require a larger ambient space to prove?
Exposition
Here's a claim that one can make in the reals but it seems to me couldn't proven without invoking [something equivalent to] the complex plane: $e^\pi$ is transcendental: $e^\pi\notin \bar {\mathbb{Q}}$. The proof [it seems to be and surely given our current tools] needs to somehow invoke the idea that $e^{\pi i}=-1$. Then we can proceed with LW Theorem. And I highly suspect with weaker tools than LW theorem, one would still need the relationship that these constants have to the circle and thus we need something like the complex numbers to get the job done. I am not sure there is a proof that it cannot be proven without invoking the complex numbers but I would wager it's doable. It seems it as Jacques Hadamard said "The shortest path between two truths in the real domain passes through the complex domain."
I wonder about claims that NEED the complex plane or simply higher dimensions for the proof.
Question
Is there a claim that one can make in the reals or complex numbers which requires the quaternions or octonions to prove?
Is there a claim that one can make in the $\mathbb{R}^n$ that isn't really provable without a larger ambient space $\mathbb{R}^{n+m_n}$?
Motivations
Sometimes Set Theorists talk about claims which aren't provable within a specific model and require an ambient model. There are claims one can make with Peano Arithmetic which aren't provable without an ambient model. Above I ask for a specific and very concrete or understandable analog to this idea.

I really like this question but I don't think you will get a satisfactory answer. It is hard to formalise claims about the real numbers which require a larger ambient space to prove. Even if we do so, the larger ambient space is unlikely to be the complex numbers.
Motivations
Unfortunately, your question differs from your motivating example in several key ways.

There are claims one can make with Peano Arithmetic which aren't provable without an ambient model.

If we interpret a claim as a statement in the language of PA, then a standard example might be Goodstein's theorem which is unprovable in (first-order) Peano Arithmetic but is provable in second-order arithmetic. Note that here provability is a property of the theory, not of the model.
The key is that we move from a theory of natural numbers to a theory of natural numbers and subsets of natural numbers.
There is not a good analogue to this notion for the reals. The first issue is interpreting what a "claim about the real numbers" even is! We would like a claim to be a statement in the language of the reals, but there are many options for this language.
A Language of the Reals
Tarski showed that the first-order language of the reals is decidable, so any first-order claim about the real numbers can be proved using the properties of real-closed fields. Thus phenomena like Goodstein's theorem cannot occur.
However, to specify the real real numbers, we need a second-order theory and a second-order language. This is where we run into trouble because theories of second-order and higher are less well-behaved. There are lots of ways to choose a language, as explained in this MO post.
For Goodstein's theorem, we needed to move to the second-order theory to find a proof. But for the reals, we need to move to the second-order theory just to define them.
To answer the question in your title:

First order claims about the real numbers do not require a larger ambient space to prove.
Higher order claims require a larger ambient space just to state.

To try to answer your question let us choose a language and call it $\mathcal{L}\mathbb{R}$.
Theories of Complex Numbers
We are going to need to define "requires the complex numbers to prove". From there, we can generalise to the quaternions, etc. If we have a theory of the complex numbers and an associated language $\mathcal{L}\mathbb{C}$, there are several conditions we would need to impose to allow statements in $\mathcal{L}\mathbb{R}$ to be interpreted in $\mathcal{L}\mathbb{C}$.
Then we are interested in statements $P$ that are unprovable in $\mathcal{L}\mathbb{R}$ but which are provable in $\mathcal{L}\mathbb{C}$. This seems to the most natural way to define "cannot be proven without invoking the complex numbers" to me.
Unfortunately, sufficiently strong theories of the real numbers can model the complex numbers. So if $\mathcal{L}\mathbb{R}$ is suitably expressive, it will not need to invoke external complex numbers, because it has its own copy of them. This probably counts as using "something like the complex numbers", but I cannot see a way to rule it out.
Conclusion
For this question to be answerable, you would need to specify the language in which a claim and its proof are expressed, as well as what it means to invoke the complex numbers in a proof.
The unprovable statements in Peano Arithmetic which are provable in ZFC do not have a clear analogue for the reals.

Very nice. I often am troubled by questions of the type "How to do X without using Y?", they do not seem "well-formulated". But I am not sufficiently experienced in writing logic to put my troubles into words.

The thing is, the theory of real numbers doesn't even need to be very strong. Complex numbers are a simple quadratic extension of the reals. All you need to understand them (given the reals) is the field structure (and if you don't have it in the picture, then complex numbers are probably irrelevant anyway). It's the opposite direction that's more complicated.
